# Video loading bar work on an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progress-bar, html5-video

I have an array of videos, each with their own thumbs that activates them, all in an array. I also have a progress bar for the videos that shows how far they've played(status, I guess), and I've manage to put one one each thumb. My question is how do I do it so that each thumb only gets a progress bar for its video, and all six don't go off at once.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to set up each of your progress bars with a sequentially numbered id and store the index of the currently playing video in a variable so that you can use that value to target the appropriate progress element using jQuery:

HTML:

```
 <div id="progress_1"><!-- any markup required for my progress bar --></div>
 <div id="progress_2"><!-- any markup required for my progress bar --></div>
 <div id="progress_3"><!-- any markup required for my progress bar --></div>
```

jQuery

```
// Update this with the index of the currently 
// playing video when the user clicks a thumb
var currentVideoIndex = 0;

// Use the currentVideoIndex to target the progress bar related to 
// the currently playing video
$('#progress_' + currentVideoIndex).css('width', percent);
```

Comment: um, where would these be placed? (sorry, I normaly work with html, not thew script, so I'm confused alot :(  )

Comment: Put the IDs on the root HTML elements of each of your progress bars and store the index of the current video in a variable in your JavaScript code. Hopefully the edit will make it clearer.